# Generate XML from a table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to generate a XML file from a table

But my xmlelement doesn't have the same name that the column in the table

How can I do that?

And I want to generate something like this:

```
<Car>
   <Brand>Ford</Ford>
   <Color>Blue</Color>
</Car>
```

How can I specify the childnodes in my XMl file?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Hi. Yes I saw that. But that don't answer my questions in fact.

Comment: I would suggest it does. `FOR XML` is *exactly* what you want here. Why is `FOR XML` *not* working for you? Have you tried it? What was that attempt?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [FOR XML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server), especially in the [Using PATH Mode examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-path-mode).

```sql
create table dbo.ThisIsNotTheTableYouAreLookingFor (
  NorIsThis varchar(10),
  TheColumn varchar(10)
);

insert dbo.ThisIsNotTheTableYouAreLookingFor (NorIsThis, TheColumn)
values ('Ford', 'Blue');

select
  NorIsThis as Brand,
  TheColumn as Color
from dbo.ThisIsNotTheTableYouAreLookingFor
for xml path('Car');
```

```xml
<Car>
  <Brand>Ford</Brand>
  <Color>Blue</Color>
</Car>
```